# Keller's Conjecture and its relation to the Hadwiger-Nelson Problem

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, coloring, tiling

Is there a relationship between the [recent result on Keller's Conjecture;](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.03740)

> The conjecture states that any tiling of identical hypercubes that fills space must contain a pair of neighbors that share an entire face.

and the Hadwiger-Nelson Problem?

I have only just heard about Keller's Conjecture and thought that it was awfully similar to the Chromatic number of the plane, and was wondering if it was possible to extend the results from it to the Hadwiger-Nelson problem.

i.e., both problems are concerned with these n-dimensional euclidean spaces, they both have their proofs rooted in dense packings, Keller's being the dense packing of dimensional analogues of the cube in this space, and Hadwiger-Nelson's being graphs with dense packings of the [moser-spindle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moser_spindle). Also both of their usage of tiling as a means proof, with:

> The upper bound of seven on the chromatic number follows from the existence of a [tessellation of the plane by regular hexagons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem#:%7E:text=The%20upper%20bound%20of%20seven,7%2Dcoloring%20of%20the%20plane.), with diameter slightly less than one, that can be assigned seven colors in a repeating pattern to form a 7-coloring of the plane.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think these two problems are similar? I don't see any reason to expect them to be related.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect Where Keller's is concerned with the n-dimensional euclidean space, the chromatic number of the plane is concerned with the 2-dimensional euclidean space. Similarly to how some proofs for the upper bound of the plane were formulated using tiling, so do the proofs for Keller's Conjecture. Where Keller's Conjecture is concerned with finding when there is a conflict (hypercubes sharing a face), the chromatic number of the plane is instead looking for graphs which do not have a conflict (having two nodes colored the same).

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect basically I figured that they are both concerned with packing elements into these infinite n-dimensional spaces. In Keller's, different dimensional analgoues of the cube are being packed, whereas in the Chromatic number of the plane, a lot of approaches for the lower bound are similarly being packed, this time with graphs which are moser-spindle dense.